# Upload a Youtube video from within an Android app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

Now that youtube has deprecated their android api, is there an alternative way to upload videos through Android Studio?

The replacment they offered is iframe but for what i can see it can only display videos.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Android Studio is a development environment, it never had the ability to upload Youtube videos. I think your question is actually "How to upload a Youtube video from within an Android app".